# JSF 2 / primefaces : graphicImage resources implicit EL variable usage

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I've successfully displayed an image using:

```
<h:graphicImage library="icon" name="primefaces/site_logo.gif"/>
```

But this failed:

```
<h:graphicImage value="#{resources['icon:primefaces/site_logo.gif']}"/>
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be `resource['...']`, not `resources['...']`.